# Tora mysql/mariadb Schema Browser Columns not working

Tags: mysql, mariadb, tora

I have database called 'shares' running on mysql on a Raspbery Pi.  I want to move this to a new install on another Pi, and as it is a new install it is MariaDB.  Both Pi's are headless, I am accessing them using Tora on my desktop.

On the old Pi I can use the schema browser and look at the columns tab.  On the new Pi when I try that I get an error -

```
Tue Jan 2 19:30:01 2018
```

Table 'shares.shares' doesn't exist

Query not active SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM :f1

The statement shares.shares does not exist is correct, but it doesn't exist on the original either.  Also if I run 'desc tablename' for a valid tablename I get the same error.

I am using the same instance of Tora to access both, so I don't think that is the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you create a database dump on the first machine, and restore it in the new install, right?

Comment: Yes thats right.  I have also just created a new database with a single table and that gives the same error.

Comment: I have done some more investigation, I created a table called 'shares' and I no longer get the error, but the problem still exists, if I use schema browser and select the columns tab it says that it is listing the fields for the selected table, however it actually displays the fields for the 'shares' table no matter which table I choose.  Same happens for display.

Comment: Can you add to the post how do you dump the database and how you restore it?...I hope that you just not just copy the files between the machines...

Comment: No I used mysqldump and then create the new database and source backupfile.  I have done some more investigation and it seems that Tora is not being developed any more, so I am currently trying out DBeaver, it looks pretty good and seems to work for both databases, so I will probably just switch to that and drop Tora.  Thanks for your help anyway.